# Angular 2+ material mat-chip-list formArray validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

How do I validate that a `mat-chip` has been added to the `mat-chip-list`. I am using ReactiveForms. I have tried with the `required` validator.

The value can be a list of names, so I need to make sure that there is atleast 1 name in my list of names before I can submit the form. If the list is empty then `mat-error` should display the error message. Using the `required` validator makes the form invalid, regardless of adding names to the list.

**EDIT: Reactive Forms**

I have tried to make a custom validator, and I am now using Reactive Forms instead of Template driven forms, but I cannot get it to work. I have edited the below code to reflect my changes and I have created this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList formArrayName="names">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let name of myForm.get('names').controls; let i=index;"
        [formGroupName]="i"
        [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(myForm, i)">
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>

       <input placeholder="Names"
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, asset)">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-error>Atleast 1 name need to be added</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**TS**

```ts
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'chip-list-validation-example',
  templateUrl: 'chip-list-validation-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chip-list-validation-example.css'],
})
export class ChipListValidationExample {
  public myForm: FormGroup;

  // name chips
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  addOnBlur = true;
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];

  // data
  data = {
    names: ['name1', 'name2']
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      names: this.fb.array(this.data.names, this.validateArrayNotEmpty)
    });
  }

  initName(name: string): FormControl {
    return this.fb.control(name);
  }

  validateArrayNotEmpty(c: FormControl) {
    if (c.value && c.value.length === 0) {
      return { 
        validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent, form: FormGroup): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add name
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      const control = <FormArray>form.get('names');
      control.push(this.initName(value.trim()));
      console.log(control);
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  remove(form, index) {
    console.log(form);
    form.get('names').removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just check if `names.length > 0`, easiest way if that is sufficient for your scenario

Comment: That will just hide the mat-error, it will not make the formControl valid. I need it to be validated.

Comment: Yes but you can write your own validator using that condition. Take a look here: https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73

Comment: I have tried to make a custom validator, and I am now using Reactive Forms instead of Template driven forms, but I cannot get it to work. See edited post. I have created this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj)

Comment: No comments since my edit. Is there not a solution to this? I have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that the chipList's `errorState` isn't set to `true` when the chipList's `FormArray` status is `INVALID`.

I'm facing the same problem and don't know why this isn't working out of the box or how this can be achieved implicitly with the chipList's form being a `FormArray`.

As a workaround you can listen to status changes from the `FormArray` and set the chipList's `errorState` manually:

```ts
@ViewChild('chipList') chipList: MatChipList;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get('names').statusChanges.subscribe(
    status => this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID'
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-gywxjz

Comment: thanks for posting this. I've spent a good amount of time on this. I wish stuff like this was documented somewhere.

Comment: This doesn't address the initial validation when chips are empty and form is submitted without changing the state of the input field.

Comment: if you initialize data = [], then validation will not work

Answer (score 5):

To be able to get the validation working on a `mat-chip-list` we have to bind both the `mat-input` and `mat-chip-list` with same `FormControl` like below

Working Stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuifjo-dxlxrp?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.html)

```html
<form [formGroup]='group'>
  <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList
                   required
                   formControlName="newFruit">
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
                (removed)="remove(fruit)">
        {{fruit.name}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input placeholder="New fruit..."
            formControlName="newFruit"
            [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
            [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
            (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" required>
    </mat-chip-list>
      <!-- add mat-error  -->
    <mat-error *ngIf="group.controls.newFruit.hasError('required')">required!</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use any of Angular's predefined validators because they are not designed to work with arrays. I manage to do it with the help of this article:

https://www.dev6.com/Angular_Material_Chips_with_Reactive_Forms_and_Custom_Validation

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have a working sample(plunker or stackblitz) ? The author of this blog did not give one and am pretty sure the html part of his demo is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

For somebody is facing with this problem. After many hours, I have found the root cause of the issue and the solution for it as is:

At function add, remove, select of chiplist, **you need to use function setValue in reactive form** to make the validation work.

For example:

```
  this.form.get('names').value.push('abc');
  this.form.get('names').setValue(this.form.get('names').value); // => this line of code will make the validation work
```

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated by [this example](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19391#issuecomment-637777513) by [mmalerba](https://github.com/mmalerba),
you can use two separate form controls: one for the mat-chip-list (this one should be the one with the required flag), and a different one for the input. Interestingly, you'll have to manually set the values of both on the addEvent:

```html
<!-- ... -->
    <mat-chip-list #chipList formControlName="names" required>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input placeholder="Names"
        [formControlName]="name"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event, asset)">
    </mat-chip-list>
    <!-- ... -->
```

```js
import {Validators} from '@angular/forms';

    # ...
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            names: [this.data.names, Validators.required],
            name: ['']
        });
    }

    # ...
    add(event: MatChipInputEvent, form: FormGroup): void {
      const input = event.input;
      const value = event.value;

      // Add name
      if ((value || '').trim()) {
        const control = <FormArray>form.get('names');
        control.push(this.initName(value.trim()));
        console.log(control);
      }

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
        input.value = '';
      }

      // update form control (necessary for correct validation)
      this.myForm.controls.name.setValue(null);
      this.myForm.controls.names.setValue(this.data.names);
    }

    # ...
}
```

Here's their [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chips-autocomplete-required-failure-txn7nn?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.ts)