# How to sync FormArray control that displays items as mat-chips inside of a single mat-form-field input, to display error messages?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `'mat-form-field'` input on which I am displaying a list of `mat-chip` elements that represent different clothing sizes. Chips can be `'L'`, `'S'` etc...
Currently, this is how I am iterating through the list of all sizes and displaying them:

```
`
<mat-chip-list formArrayName="sizes" #chipList [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">

          <mat-chip #chipRef
            *ngFor="let gearSize of gearItemForm.controls['sizes'].value; let i=index"            
            [selected]="gearSize.size.available"  
            (click)="gearSize.size.available = !gearSize.size.available; onSelectedChipSize()"  
            [color]="gearSize.size.color">{{ sizeEnum[gearSize.size.size] }}  
          </mat-chip>

        </mat-chip-list>

          <input
          matInput
          [formGroupName]="0"
          placeholder="Gear sizes..."
          [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
          style="display: none;"
          class="gear-size-label"
         >
          <span>Is form array sizes invalid: {{gearItemForm.get('sizes').touched}}</span>

        <mat-error *ngIf="gearItemForm.get('sizes').invalid && gearItemForm.get('sizes').touched">Please select a size</mat-error>

      </mat-form-field>
`
```

This is how I am setting up my form:

```
`
this.gearItemForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control(name, Validators.required),
      price: this.fb.control(price, Validators.required),
      sizes: this.fb.array(sizesForm, this.requireSize()),
      inStock: this.fb.control(inStock)
})
`
```

Where the `sizesForm` is this:

```
`
for (let index = 0; index < this.gearSizes.length; index++) {
          sizesForm.push(this.fb.group({
           'size': this.fb.control(sizes[index])
        }))        
      }
`
```

My problem is that I have a custom validator, that requires a user to select a size of an item before posting new item to the store. Everything works as expected, but I am trying to display an error message if user does not select any sizes. Currently it's all working, because I disable the form 'submit' button if the form is invalid. If I do not select any chips then the form's 'submit' button is disabled. I cannot however, get the form to display any errors using `'mat-error'` even though `<mat-error *ngIf="gearItemForm.get('sizes').invalid">Please select a size</mat-error>` returns true meaning its invalid.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a good amount of time on trial and error and searching on stack-overflow. I came across this SO post that has solved my issue:

[Angular 2+ material mat-chip-list formArray validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483323/angular-2-material-mat-chip-list-formarray-validation)

The problem was that when the '`FormArray`' control was set to invalid, the `Chip-list` component was not reflecting this change. Thus no error messages were displayed. You have to manually change the `errorState` value of `mat-chip-list` component when your form control becomes `invalid` something like this:

```
@ViewChild('chipList') chipList: MatChipList;

ngOnInit() {
    this.gearItemForm.get('sizes').statusChanges.subscribe(status => 
          this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID' ? true : false)
}
```

Then in your HTML template:

```
<mat-form-field id="sizes">        
        <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Gear sizes...</mat-placeholder>

        <mat-chip-list formArrayName="sizes" #chipList [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">

          <mat-chip #chipRef  
            *ngFor="let gearSize of gearItemForm.controls['sizes'].value; let i=index"                    
            [selected]="gearSize.available"  
            (click)="gearSize.available = !gearSize.available; onSelectedChipSize()"  
            [color]="gearSize.color">{{ sizeEnum[gearSize.size] }}  
          </mat-chip>

        </mat-chip-list>

        <mat-error *ngIf="sizes.invalid && sizes.touched">Please select a size</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```